# HTML5 canvas Mouseover event

Tags: javascript, html

How do I bind a mouseover or any event for that matter to a drawn object on the canvas? For instance, I tried this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

//STEP ONE
var stepOneRec = ctx.rect(20, 60, 266, 50);
ctx.stroke();
stepOneRec.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { alert('it works!'); });
```

On one site I looked at it showed a method using Kinetic.js. If that's the only way, I'll use it, I just assume that there's a way to bind events to drawn elements without extra plug-ins. Sorry Canvas noob. I made a fiddle with my code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jyBSZ/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I started this as a posted comment, then realized it's an actual answer.)

Unfortunately, in javascript on it's own, you can't.  There are no canvas objects, just the canvas as a whole, and whatever you drew on to its context.  Plugins like kinetic can make objects for you, but the whole point of canvas is that the browser can think of it as a single static image.

If you want to, you can bind mousemove events to the canvas, track its position and the position where you drew stuff, and imply on your own that it's over "that object" (effectively what the plugins do), but it's all mousemove events on a single canvas rather than mouseover events on components of it.  (You could even make your event binding simulate a mouseover event for the "objects", but underneath, it's still based on checking movement and checking your own object setup.)

Comment: Ohh! I was on this site (http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/blob/03/) and I was trying to see how he handled his mouse events, I guess it's just through corrdinartes.

Comment: @user2287474 He's minimized his main code, which makes it really hard to tell.  Inside js/blob.min.js, I can see that most of his functions for dealing with events are first, but it's too hard to interpret well.  (I see things looking at keyboard presses and touch events).  He created objects to hold the rendering information, but somewhere in there, he rendered all of the objects on each animation.

Comment: I think he means the mousemove event. Use the mousemove event to track position, then a conditional statement to "do something" when it arrives in the area of the object.

Comment: Fair point, Sephethus, thanks.  I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The objects drawn within a canvas element are not HTML elements, just pixels, and therefore will not throw DOM events the way that HTML elements would.

You would need to track the locations of your objects yourself and handle the canvas' `onmousemove` event in order to determine when the mouse is over one of your drawn objects.

Answer (score 2):

you can use jCanvas, take a look [here](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/)

i made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyBSZ/73/)  example for your problem.

just modify next callbacks for desired result

```
 function mouseOut(layer){
$("#mouse-over-text").html('none options selected');
}

function mouseIn(layer){
$("#mouse-over-text").html(getTextForId(layer.name));
}
```