# Create a button out of a javascript canvas object

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('navigation');
  if(canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    //shape 1
    ctx.moveTo(300, 1120);
    ctx.lineTo(230, 1070);
    ctx.lineTo(160, 880);
    ctx.lineTo(170, 770);
    ctx.lineTo(260, 640);
    ctx.lineTo(350, 710);
    ctx.lineTo(360, 820);
    //shape 2
    ctx.moveTo(340, 1050);
    ctx.lineTo(390, 820);
    ctx.lineTo(450, 710);
    ctx.lineTo(450, 810);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="navigation" width="1500" height="1500"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've got this snippet of code, and I was wondering if it's possible to make Shape 1 and Shape 2 independently clickable buttons, each redirecting to a different webpage.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: because the canvas element is purely for drawing shapes and stuff the browser is not able to get access into it, therefore its not possible to access the shapes inside a canvas. Instead i would try the <svg> element which you can then create 2 of and it should work pretty well. - also check out svg's clippath and assign that to a link element will restrict the clickable area.

Comment: It looks like you'll have to write code to track canvas objects yourself or look for a helper library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055290/html5-canvas-mouseover-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of achieving it... instead of using canvas here the svg object gets used... though using an experimental feature (clip-path, css property)

```html
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
svg {
 display: block;
 height: 0;
}
</style>
<svg>
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="c1">
   <path
    d="
    M 300, 1120
    L 230, 1070
    L 160, 880
    L 170, 770
    L 260, 640
    L 350, 710
    L 360, 820
    Z
    M 340, 1050
    L 390, 820
    L 450, 710
    L 450, 810
    Z
   "/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
<style type="text/css">
a {
 display: block;
 width: 1500px;
 height: 1500px;
 background: black;
 transition: all .2s;
 font-size: 0;
    clip-path: url(#c1);
}
a:hover {
 background: lime;
}
</style>
<a href="#1">Click me...</a>
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution I was looking for. I'm very new to JS so I didn't know SVG was a thing, but this is precisely what I was trying to do. a change to your code I made was create a new `clipPath` for the second shape, and then use another `href`. Then I wrapped it in a div that has position set to absolute. In this way, it overlapped all the different shapes I wanted to construct the crystal-looking nagivation panel.

Thank you for the solution and for the big nudge in the right direction.

Comment: well svg isn't js, but this is a good alternative to what I was trying to accomplish with js