# How can I get my mouseover to work within the scope that I want?

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, mouseevent

Im just getting back into the swing of things with javascript and this may be simple but its flying over my head. I have here a canvas script which I want to simply mouse over the rectangle and fill it in with black.

```js
//Establish context
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//create rectangle
ctx.rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

// when moused over the rectangle, fill it black
function fill() {
  if (event.clientX <= 20 && event.clientY <= 20) {
    ctx.fill();
  }

  console.log(event.clientX + " " + event.clientY);
}

// simple test that shows the position of the mouse on when the mouse moves
function test() {
  console.log("X: " + event.clientX + "Y: " + event.clientY);
}

c.addEventListener("mouseover", fill);
c.addEventListener("mousemove", test);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="250" style="border: 2px solid black"></canvas>
```

Here is where I'm missing something. When I mouse of the canvas element, it triggers the mouse over event. But How can I prevent the mouse over event from happening until Im only within the rectangle constraints?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055290/html5-canvas-mouseover-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to inspect the `clientX` and `clientY` position of the event against the rectangle's perimeter. Also make sure to pass `event` to your `fill` function.

```
c.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    if(event.clientX >=0 && event.clientX <= 20){
        if(event.clientY >=0 && event.clientY <= 20){
            fill(event);
        }
    }
});

function fill(event)
{
    if(event.clientX <= 20 && event.clientY <= 20)
    {
        ctx.fill();
    }

    console.log(event.clientX + " " + event.clientY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some answers. This is mine:

I've added a function to detect the position of the mouse on the canvas: `oMousePos`. Please read about [the method getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Also I'm using `mousemove` instead of `mouseover` since `mouseover` is fired when the mouse is moved onto the canvas. `mousemove` is fired  **while** the mouse is moved over the canvas.

To detect if the mouse is over the rect I'm using the method [isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)

```js
//Establish context
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 500;
c.height = 250;

var mouse={}

//create rectangle
ctx.rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

// when moused over the rectangle, fill it black
function fill(event) {
  mouse = oMousePos(c, event);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  // if the mouse is in path fill()
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

c.addEventListener("mousemove", fill);

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{border: 2px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**mouseover** will only fire one time when the cursor enters the canvas. You can just use the **mousemove** event and compare coordinates. Here's an example that fills when it enters and clears when it exits:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

function fill()
{
    if(event.clientX <= 20 && event.clientY <= 20)
    {
         ctx.fill();       
    }else{
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }
    console.log(event.clientX + " " + event.clientY);

}

c.addEventListener("mousemove", fill);
```

Here's the jsfiddle in action: https://jsfiddle.net/dL18v63w/

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the position of your mouse depending on several things:

- position of the canvas
- position of the mouse
- style of the canvas

```js
// Establish context
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Get canvas position
var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
var borderWidth = parseInt(c.style.borderWidth);
    
// Create rectangle
ctx.rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
ctx.stroke();

// Fill the rectangle
function fill() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
}

// Empty the rectangle
function empty() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();  
}

function onmousemove() {
  // Need to calculate the position of the mouse according to:
  // - the position of the canvas
  // - the border of the canvas (2px)
  if (event.clientX <= rect.left + borderWidth + 20 && event.clientY <= rect.top + borderWidth + 20) {
    fill();
  } else {
    empty();
  }
}
    
// Check the position of the mouse after every move
c.addEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);
// Empty the rectangle when the mouse leaves the canvas
c.addEventListener('mouseout', empty);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Railio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="250" style="border: 2px solid black">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the part that checks the mouse-coordinates for being < 20 to your test-function and give it as parameter event. That should do the trick, if I understand your question right. You can't prevent the mousover-event from happening until the mouse is over the rect, if you add the Event-Listener to the canvas.